# Defining a Generic Method in a Trait When Using Algebraic Data Type in Scala

Tags: scala, abstract-data-type

I have defined an abstract data type, and i wanted to make it fairly general and scalable.

However, scala type system is giving me a nightmare.

```
sealed trait Tree[+A] {
  def evaluateTree(): A = this match {
    case Leaf(value) => value
    case Branch_A1(op, left) => op(evaluateTree(left))
    case Branch_A2(op, left, right) => op(evaluateTree(left),evaluateTree(right))
  }
}
case object EmptyTree extends Tree[Nothing]
case class Leaf[A](value: A) extends Tree[A]
case class Branch_A1[A](op: A => A, left: Tree[A]) extends Tree[A]
case class Branch_A2[A](op: (A,A) => A, left: Tree[A], right: Tree[A]) extends Tree[A]
```

**A** would be e.g. Double. So in this case i have a tree which has branches that represent functions of one and two arguments (Branch_A1, Branch_A2)

However it does not compile. In `op(evaluateTree(left))` it says that "it cannot resolve ... with such reference".

I could take the function away from the class into a more functional pattern but i want to do it following an object design. The only way i can get it into compiling is to do:

```
sealed trait Tree[+A] {
  def evaluateTree(t: Tree[A]): A = this match {
    case Leaf(value) => value
    case Branch_A1(op, left) => op(evaluateTree(left))
    case Branch_A2(op, left, right) => op(evaluateTree(left),evaluateTree(right))
  }
}
case object EmptyTree extends Tree[Nothing]
case class Leaf[A](value: A) extends Tree[A]
case class Branch_A1[A](op: A => A, left: Tree[A]) extends Tree[A]
case class Branch_A2[A](op: (A,A) => A, left: Tree[A], right: Tree[A]) extends Tree[A]
```

which is stupid since i need to pass it the instance of the object.

I need to tell the compiler that `this` is an `Tree[A]`. So i have tried:

```
sealed trait Tree[+A] {

  this: Tree[A] =>

  def evaluateTree(): A = this match {
    case Leaf(value) => value
    case Branch_A1(op, left) => op(evaluateTree(left))
    case Branch_A2(op, left, right) => op(evaluateTree(left),evaluateTree(right))
  }
}
```

Still the compiler does not let me go, the error is the same actually.
How can i solve this??

Comment: Well, since you want to do it using object design, you should be calling methods instead of functions in your first snipet: `op(left.evaluateTree())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your receivers are screwed up. `evaluateTree` does not take arguments. I'm assuming you want to evaluate the subtree, as in `op(evaluateTree(left))` should instead be `op(left.evaluateTree())`

```
def evaluateTree(): A = this match {
  case Leaf(value) => value
  case Branch_A1(op, left) => op(left.evaluateTree())
  case Branch_A2(op, left, right) => op(left.evaluateTree(),right.evaluateTree())
}
```

Comment: you're absolutely right. i was sleeping, scala type system is giving me such a hard time that i don't even see the obvious. i just assume that is some problem with the typesystem -.-